# h_addr_list order

Tags: c, networking, gethostbyname

I want to understand in which order are the elements of `h_addr_list` sorted when I get the `hostent` from `gethostbyname`.

Basically, I'm working on a very old function that gets a `hostent` struct from `gethostbyname`, and returnes `h_addr` to the caller. I'm trying to figure out which address will be returned in case of multiple active interfaces.

Google and source-code browsing could not help me here. Is there documentation or some information on the order of `h_addr_list`?

P.S. I'm working on code for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Not an answer because I'm not sure if it applies here, but for dns queries at least it's common to "shuffle" the order for each request so that if a server has more than one address they'll all get some use. Meaning that the order is essentially random for each request and not something you can rely on.

Comment: Neither the official manual page for [`gethostbyname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gethostbyname.html) or of the [`<netdb.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/netdb.h.html) defines an order. So my guess is that there is no order, and that it might even change between calls.

Comment: If you are laying hands on this part of a program, you should consider rewriting it to use `getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()`, as appropriate. This would make the program future-proof.

Comment: I agree, I wish I could update that entire lib, let alone that one function, but it's *way* out of our current scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think that there is "an order" in the first place? What would make any particular address more worthy of being listed first?

In other words, I don't think there is a well-defined order for the addresses. You simply get all the addresses that are available to the lookup system.

Comment: I figured that there's some arbitrary ordering (i.e. lowest lexicographic mac-address first), just because I assume an order would be preferable to lack thereof.